# How to fix Phonegap / Cordova external URL issue

Tags: cordova

I am trying to link to an external url from a link in my app (this used to work in older version of Phonegap) but I get to a web page that I can't navigate back from. Closing the app and re-opening just goes back to the webpage, not the app page where the link was.
Really need some help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using Childbrowser plugin for Phonegap. This is quite handy when it comes to dealing with external links. It allows you to open an external link within your app. Here are some useful links to go about it:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser
https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser

This could give you some idea:

http://moduscreate.com/opening-all-urls-with-phonegaps-childbrowser-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for the tips - I'll have a go. Apologies if my question was a bit basic but I'm new to this and struggling a bit.

Comment: you might also need to check each platform for specifics on opening a new browser tab or window if you don't want to go the Childbrowser way

Answer (score 0):

You can also use InAppBrowser -

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser